# How to find the JOSE signing key?

Tags: openid-connect, jose, node-jose

My goal is to determine which **kid** is used to sign a specific payload:

```js
      try {
        bearerToken = getBearerToken(req.headers);
        console.log("token", { bearerToken });
    
        // if the bearerToken is signed by another kid, how do i know which key to use?
    
        let verifyBearerTokenKeystore = await jose.JWK.asKeyStore(mypubkey);
        verifyBearerTokenResult = await jose.JWS.createVerify(
          verifyBearerTokenKeystore
        ).verify(bearerToken);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.status(403).send("invalid bearer token");
      }
```

[Full source](https://github.com/kaihendry/my-first-jose/commit/29b02685169c4f78a5bb5e36d97dd39ebb8af600)

If I purposely broke this `"kid": "z2U_owemqRLOQYEhiSX1fUrPp72hXSG6dKy8qUvu1DY"` in `ks.json`, I expect node-jose to say:

```
Error: kid z2U_owemqRLOQYEhiSX1fUrPp72hXSG6dKy8qUvu1DY not found
```

not

```
Error: no key found
```

How do I make it tell me the kid (key id) it expects? Furthermore [how do verifiers](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RotateSigKeys) extract the **jwks_uri**?

Comment: I think the solution to the problem is for me to decode the header from the jws, but I am not sure which library function does that for me.

Comment: https://github.com/cisco/node-jose/issues/330